# 2 different effects with 1 hover?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to adjust the following code so that when I hover over the existing image, not only does that image change, but it also changes an image in a different place on the site.

This is what I am using (with some corresponding javascript)...

```
<figcaption class="content"><a class="typeB" href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image1','','../graphics/life2.jpg',1)"><img src="../graphics/life1.jpg" width="300" height="25" id="Image1"/></a>
</figcaption>
```

So, the code above says to change when hovering over "life2.jpg" change it to "life1.jpg"...but I also want to add in so that hovering over "life2.jpg" will also change "life4.jpg" to "life3.jpg".

Thank you so much in advance!! :)

C*

Comment: can u put it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: call a java script method; and do all actions in method.

Comment: What are the MM_ methods doing? You should change or extend them.

Comment: @Chanckjh I am quite new...how do I put it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: The jsfiddle with your question code: [jsfiddle.net/mnZd2](http://jsfiddle.net/mnZd2).

Answer (score 0):

Call a javascript with all the actions like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
function MM_swapImage(){ 
    document.getElementById("Image1").src = Image1.src.replace("http://bit.ly/12DYRi4", "http://bit.ly/T4xkFG");
    document.getElementById("Image2").src = Image2.src.replace("http://bit.ly/12DYRi4", "http://bit.ly/T4xkFG");   
}

function MM_swapImgRestore(){  
    document.getElementById("Image1").src = Image1.src.replace("http://bit.ly/T4xkFG", "http://bit.ly/12DYRi4");
    document.getElementById("Image2").src = Image2.src.replace("http://bit.ly/T4xkFG", "http://bit.ly/12DYRi4"); 
}
</script>

<head>  
<body>

<figcaption class="content">
       <a class="typeB" href="#" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage()">
           <img src="http://bit.ly/12DYRi4" width="50" height="50" id="Image1"/>
       </a>
       <br><br>
       <img src="http://bit.ly/12DYRi4" width="50" height="50" id="Image2"/>
</figcaption>

</body>
</html>
```

You can see it in action on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EW4ZZ/2/

This should get you started.